# LLVM load array index

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

It is very shameful that when searching array subscription for `llvm`, I cannot find any concrete results and most of answers on stackoverflow are actually a hint for experts than a solution.

What I am after is how to load `my_array[my_index]`. My llvm version is 10.0.0.

I am after a solution working on both global and local array and any variable index.

```
llvm::Value * address_of_array = ...
llvm::Value * index = ... // a variable index (not a constant index)
llvm::LoadInst * loader = ??????
```

what should I place instead of the question marks?

---

Note:

I create the array from the following steps

```
llvm::Type * element_type = ...
llvm::ArrayType* array_type = llvm::ArrayType::get(element_type, array_length);
llvm::AllocaInst * alloc_inst = new llvm::AllocaInst(array_type, 0, "array_name", basic_block);
```

Comment: Are you actually intending to write a patch for LLVM?

Comment: @sweenish, I didn't get your point.

Comment: My point is that if you're not working on LLVM's codebase, you probably don't need these LLVM-specific values. Just use regular arrays and/or vectors. As far as downvote for what, your question lacks details and clarity. If you spent your energy providing enough context instead of insulting the community you're trying to get an answer from, you might have more success.

Comment: @sweenish, I am using llvm for my compiler code generation. Not sure what you mean by regular arrays/vectors.

Comment: FWIW, languages such as Ruby, Java and C have rather different array types when viewed at a compiler's level of detail. I suspect that once you understand what your array type is, you'll be able to make use of the "hints" you've found.